# How would I iterate and retrieve the element with the highest innerText value using Javascript?

Tags: javascript, html

How to get element with the highest value using javascript?

```
<div class="score">1</div>
<div class="score">0</div>
<div class="score">4</div>
<div class="score">0</div>
<div class="score">2</div>
```

Comment: What code have you attempted? Please add that to your question as a [mcve]. You mentioned "iteration" so have a look over [the documentation for loops/iteration](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Loops_and_iteration).

Comment: Get all elements via `document.querySelectorAll('.score')`, convert them to an `Array`, then use `.reduce((max, el) => Math.max(max, Number(el.textContent), 0)`

Comment: @David that would return the highest number not the element that contains it which is what I think the OP wants. That said it might be a partial solution to the problem.

Comment: @Andy Oops, you're right. @yocnat: Use something like: `.reduce((match, el) => !match  ||  Number(el.textContent) > Number(match.textContent) ? el : match, null)`

Answer (score 0):

Access all the elements that have a class of "score" by using document.getElementsByClassName it will return an array.
Then iterate through the array and implement the logic that will get you the greatest value.
You can use the below code

```
const elements = document.getElementsByClassName("score");
let greatestNumber = parseInt(elements[0].innerHTML)
let elementOfGreatestNumber = null
for(let index=1;index<elements.length;index++) {
  const currentNumber = parseInt(elements[index].innerHTML)
  if(currentNumber > greatestNumber) {
    greatestNumber = currentNumber
    elementOfGreatestNumber = elements[index]
  }
}
console.log(elementOfGreatestNumber)
```

Comment: comparing strings, not numbers

Comment: A few things: `.getElementsByClassName` does _not_ return an `Array`. It returns a `NodeList` which is something _different_ (but `array-like`). Also, you had the same misunderstanding I had in my first comment :-) Your solution gives the greatest number, not the _element_ that contains the greatest number.

Comment: let me update the answer according to your requirement.

Answer (score 0):

##### Method 1 - time complexity O(n log n)

first, sort the array in descending order.
then get the first item.

`b.innerText - a.innerText` js will automatically convert string values to numbers.

```
const scores = Array.from(document.getElementsByClassName("score"))
const elm = scores.sort((a, b) => b.innerText - a.innerText)[0]
```

##### Method 2 - time complexity O(n)

as Devid mentioned, you can also do it using reduce method. this is a much more effective way to do it.

```js
const scores = Array.from(document.getElementsByClassName("score"))
const elm = scores.reduce((a, b) => a.innerText - b.innerText > 0 ? a : b)

console.log(elm)
```

```html
<div class="score">1</div>
<div class="score">0</div>
<div class="score">4</div>
<div class="score">0</div>
<div class="score">2</div>
```

e.g.

```js
const log = console.log;

log('3' - '1')
log('-3' - '1')
```

Answer (score 0):

Initialise a `number` variable to zero, and a `selected` variable to hold a div element.

Get all the div elements with [`querySelectorAll`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll) and [iterate over them](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach). Check to see if the the text content from the each div is greater than `number`. If it is set `number` to that value, and assign the div to `selected`.

After the iteration you have the element stored in `selected`. Here I'm adding a `selected` class to it.

```js
const divs = document.querySelectorAll('div');

let number = 0;
let selected;

divs.forEach(div => {
  if (div.textContent > number) {
    number = div.textContent;
    selected = div;
  }
});

selected.classList.add('selected');
```

```css
.selected { background-color: lightgreen; }
div { padding: 0.25em; 0.4em; width: 100px; }
```

```html
<div class="score">1</div>
<div class="score">0</div>
<div class="score">4</div>
<div class="score">0</div>
<div class="score">2</div>
```